# Quick thing, make file accessible only by admin, php

Tags: php

I have this welcome.php which the administrator is redirected when he is authenticated, i have this other hostess.php which i want it to be displayed only to the administrator, i mean, noone should have access unless he or her is logged in.

The file of welcome.php contains this small code:

How can i insert hostess.php there?

```
<?php include('lock.php'); ?> 
<body> 
<div id="menu">  
<ul> 
<li><a href="logout.php">log out</a></li> 
</ul> 
</div> 
<h1> Welcome <?php echo $login_session; ?> </h1>
</body>
```

login page code:

```
<?php
include("config.php");
session_start();
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
{
// username and password sent from Form
$myusername=addslashes($_POST['username']);
$mypassword=addslashes($_POST['password']);

$sql="SELECT id FROM admin WHERE username='$myusername' and passcode='$mypassword'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
$row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
$active=$row['active'];
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);


// If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row
if($count==1)
{
session_register("myusername");
$_SESSION['login_user']=$myusername;

header("location: welcome.php");
}
else
{
$error="Your Login Name or Password is invalid";
}
}
?>
<form action="" method="post">
<label>UserName :</label>
<input type="text" name="username"/><br />
<label>Password :</label>
<input type="password" name="password"/><br/>
<input type="submit" value=" Submit "/><br />
</form>
```

Comment: it won't make it acessible only for the administrator..

Comment: I have a login page, with a session there, if you see i'm going to update the question with the login page code please..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do conditional includes then you should just add a check to see if the user is logged in and include the file if they are. I don't know how you implemented the login and authentication stuff but based on the info you provided it would be like so:

```
<body> 
    <?php include('lock.php'); 
    if($login_session != 'admin') { // or however else you would check the login status
        echo "<h1> Please Log In </h1>";
    } else {
        include('hostess.php'); // include and display all the rest of the stuff
        // display the stuff
    ?>
    <div id="menu">  
        <ul> 
            <li><a href="logout.php">log out</a></li> 
        </ul>
    </div>
    <h1> Welcome <?php echo $login_session; ?> </h1>
    <?php } // close else ?>
</body>
```